# how to logout user on browser tab or window closes

Tags: login, session, logout

How to logout a user when he closes the tab/window ?

If no, it is possible to clear the session after specific time? How to do that?

Comment: If I am reading the question right, this is either a Javascript question and off-topic here, or a (near) duplicate of this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108399/extending-auth-cookie-expiration-based-on-user-role

Comment: It doesn't seem to work properly on custom login. 
When Session expires, I'm unable to login .

Answer (score 2):

I worked long on this one. It is because of the WordPress remember me. Use this code in your theme's `functions.php` and it should fix your issue:

```
function myplugin_cookie_expiration( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ) {
    return $remember ? $expiration : 180;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'myplugin_cookie_expiration', 99, 3 );
```

Comment: hey is it possible to add the user expiration time for a user role exemple for client role?